# Restrict a Template to be useable by Wrapping

Tags: generics, rust, numbers, traits, integer-overflow

I'm trying to add two numbers with integer-overflow in Rust. The number type should be configurable to do this I'm trying to use a template. I than hand over the overflow operation to the [Wrapping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.Wrapping.html) struct. This is the code:

```
// T: Copy + Add + Sub + Default + From<u8> + Into<char> + UpperHex
pub fn inc_value(&mut self, value: T) {
    self.buffer[self.index] = (Wrapping(self.buffer[self.index]) + Wrapping(value)).0;
}
```

This sadly results in a compiling error because Wrapping is (of course) not always implemented for T. Sadly Wrapping seems not to be using any traits, instead it is implemented for certain values.

**How can I restrict T to be implemented by Wrapping? Or is there a better way to archive my overall goal?**

This is the compiler error I get:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `std::num::Wrapping<T>`
  --> src\buffer.rs:28:70
   |
28 |         self.buffer[self.index] = (Wrapping(self.buffer[self.index]) + Wrapping(value)).0;
   |                                    --------------------------------- ^ --------------- std::num::Wrapping<T>
   |                                    |
   |                                    std::num::Wrapping<T>
   |
   = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Add` might be missing for `std::num::Wrapping<T>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The note in the error messages tells you what to do; you need to add the constraint:

```
where
    Wrapping<T>: Add,
```